# O que é Read Process Memory?

Tags: memória

Eu queria saber o que é Read Process Memory. Pois estou tentando fazer um Bot para um jogo, e me disseram que precisaria utilizar isso, para ver onde por exemplo a vida do personagem esta armazenada na memoria.

Comment: Sem contexto é um pouco complicado responder. Nem linguagem você diz. Será que é isto que estão falando? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Essa é um pergunta abrangente e complexa, mas `Read Process Memory` é o processo de ler a memória, no seu caso a vida do personagem que está armazenada na memória.

O **primeiro passo** seria encontrar o endereço da memória, utilizando um editor de memória, por exemplo o Cheat Engine(bastante usado em jogos).

**Segundo passo** seria editar o dado nesse endereço de memória.

Agora como fazer isso depende da Linguagem de programação que está usando.